# "I wished I could take her to Turkey" Is the tense correct?

Tags: tense, verb-forms, subordinate-clauses

I know that **wish + could/would** is used to refer to **future**. Now, if the job of wishing took place in the past, do we still use could/would or we change it?

> I wished I could take her to Turkey, when I looked at her excited
>   face.

Comment: You are *absolutely* right!

Answer (score 1):

If the verb **wish** is in the past we still use could/would but the meaning would change thusly:

> I wished I could take her to Turkey.

which is quite equivalent to:

> I wish I could have taken her to Turkey.

means that *now* you describe your regret about that past event.

If the present of **wish** is used:

> I wish I could take her to Turkey.

means that *now* you express your feelings about this situation which refers to future events.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tense is correct since as you said, the "wishing" was in the past. Additionally the "taking to Turkey" was not yet done at the time - this is the future tense that the sentence was referring to, not the wishing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sentence, I think that you could have used wished + could have + past participle of the verb. Your sentence gave off the impression of "what could have been" when you talked about the look that you saw in your face.

In any case, I would suggest going to [this discussion of the usage of "could have" in sentences](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/couldhave/menu.php).